# Fire itself does not show in final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, smoke-simulation

Just followed the campfire animation. Fire, smoke, and embers all show in <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> view and also in <kbd>F12</kbd> render.  But when going to full animation all I get is the plane, the sticks and a glow. no fire, smoke, or embers.

Comment: What render engine are you using?

Comment: blender 2.76b. i know i saw on one topic, it was switching between cpu and gpu. But mine does not give that option

Comment: Are you using Cycles or Blender Render for the render engine?

Comment: i am using cycles.

Comment: Please edit your question and post an image of your material nodes for the domain. Also make sure you are not previewing with a transparent background (turn Film-Transparent off)

Comment: !http://postimg.org/image/6nbotlm7n/7728b292/

Comment: and transparent film is turned off

Comment: If your GPU does not meet requirements GPU rendering will not be an option.

Comment: The `flame` property shouldn't be capitalized; that's why there's no fire (at least one of reasons). However this doesn't explain why the smoke isn't seen. Make sure you played animation until smoke was emitted.